# Place Matplotlib tick labels at y=0

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, axis-labels

I have a graph where the `yaxis` ranges from `-3` to `3`. Does anyone know how I can modify the `xticks` or their corresponding `xtick labels` so they show at the `y=0` level?

Thanks

```
ind = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.4
width2 = 0.73
width3 = .85

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5), facecolor='white')

application = ax.bar(ind, values3, width3, color = 'g', alpha = .25)
admit = ax.bar(ind+((width3-width2)/2), values2, width2, color = '#537DDE', alpha = .6)
matric = ax.bar(ind+((width3-width)/2), values, width, color = '#E13F2A', alpha = .9)

ax.set_axis_bgcolor('white')
plt.xticks(ind)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation = -90)
ax.set_xticks(ind+(width/2))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation = -90`